# Flutter Futurebuilder snapshot has no data

Tags: flutter, dart, future, flutter-futurebuilder

After the first Log In in my App I want to fetch the userdata with a Futurebuilder. Therefore I want to fetch the data from firestore and store the values in a static Helper class:

```
/// Helper Class
class UserManager {
  static Map<String, dynamic> userdata = null;
}

class FireBaseHandler {

  final CollectionReference usersCol = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(
      'users');
  final myUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  /// fetch UserData
  Future getUserData() async {
    try {
      await usersCol
          .doc(myUser.uid)
          .get().then((value) => UserManager.userdata = value.data());
      return UserManager.userdata;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
}

      /// Futurebuilder in main Code

      FireBaseHandler handler = FireBaseHandler();
      return FutureBuilder(
                      future: handler.getUserData(), /// get userData and store it in Helper class
                      builder: (context, userDataSnapshot) {
                        if (userDataSnapshot.hasData) {
                          print(UserManager.userdata);
                          return HomeScreen();
                        } else {
                          return Scaffold(
                            body: Center(
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                      });
```

The Problem is that the snapshot from the Futurebuilder never has Data so `userDataSnapshot.hasData` is never true and it stays in loading Screen. Only when I hot reload the snapshot has Data and I go to the homescreen. Whats the Problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the way you initialize `UserManager.userdata` in a lambda function inside the `then (() {...})` this initialization is local to this function, reason why `UserManager.userdata` remains `null`
try to do as in the example below :

```
  Future getUserData() async {
     UserManager.userdata = (await usersCol.doc(myUser.uid).get()).data();
     return UserManager.userdata;
    
  }
```

I think the value of `UserManager.userdata` will be available only in `getUserData()`
if you want to use `UserManager.userdata` in another class, I guess it will be null,

Good way below, your function got just to return

```
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getUserData() async {
    return  (await usersCol.doc(myUser.uid).get()).data();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix `async` / `await` and `.then`, they both do the same but the two syntaxes can't be mixed. Also set the appropriate data type for your `Future` function and return the result of database fetch. You don't really need `try/catch`, you will handle errors in the `FutureBuilder`:

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getUserData() async {
    return await usersCol.doc(myUser.uid).get();
}
```

```
return FutureBuilder(
  future: handler.getUserData(), /// get userData and store it in Helper class
  builder: (context, userDataSnapshot) {
    if (userDataSnapshot.hasError) {
        return const Text('Error');
    }
    if (userDataSnapshot.hasData) {
      if (!snapshot.data!.exists) {
        return const Text('Document not found');
      }
      else {
        UserManager.userdata = userDataSnapshot.data!.data();
        print(UserManager.userdata);
        return HomeScreen();
      }
    }
    // still loading
    else {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      );
    }
  });
```